# Error E1578: el valor de la etiqueta de caso ya ha aparecido en este modificador en la línea xx, al utilizar switch-case

Tags: c++, switch

Actualmente estoy intentando programar un pequeño menú para un juego de textos y decisiones y me sale el error siguiente:

> Error (activo)    E1578   el valor de la etiqueta de caso ya ha aparecido en este modificador en la línea 21.

Este error me aparece concretamente en el segundo caso donde aparece la 'Q'.

Esta es la parte del código donde me sale el error:

```cpp
    char selection = ' ';

    cin >> selection;

    switch (selection) 
    {
        case 'P' || 'p':
        startgame();
        break;

        case 'Q' || 'q':
        return;
        break;
    }
}
```

¿Alguien me puede decir qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No uses el operador `||` como parte de la etiqueta, en vez de eso escribe dos veces el caso: `case 'P': case: 'p':`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como digo en mi comentario, el uso del operador `||` en una etiqueta para `case` está mal.

Lo que puedes hacer es escribir 2 casos, uno para cada etiqueta, por ejemplo:

```cpp
char selection = ' ';

cin >> selection;

switch (selection) 
{
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
      startgame();
      break;
    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
      return;
      // break; <= si haces return arriba, no necesitas este break;
}
```

O de forma más compacta:

```cpp
char selection = ' ';

cin >> selection;

switch (selection) 
{
    case 'P': case 'p':
      startgame();
      break;
    case 'Q': case 'q':
      return;
      // break; <= si haces return arriba, no necesitas este break;
}
```

Si entiendes el funcionamiento en "cascada" de `switch ... case`, comprenderás rápidamente cómo usarlo de forma efectiva. En el ejemplo anterior, si el valor de `selection` es 'P' o 'p', realizará la misma acción. Esto es porque cuando coincide con 'P' ejecutará todo lo que hay en el bloque para su etiqueta, y como no hay una sentencia `break` seguirá ejecutando (en cascada) el código a continuación, que es efectivamente el bloque para la etiqueta 'p'.

El operador `||` es un operador lógico y no debería ser usado como parte de una etiqueta `case`, a menos que estés probando un valor tipo `boolean`. Por ejemplo:

```cpp
int main() {
  bool day = true;
  switch (day) {
  case false || 0:
    cout << "Noche";
    break;
  case true:
    cout << "Día";
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, aunque esto se puede hacer, no es realmente práctico, es totalmente desaconsejado usar los operadores lógicos para etiquetas de `switch ... case`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Okay, super, he probado lo que me dijiste y ahora sí que funciona. Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta rápida!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer estos cambios

```
char selection = ' ';

cin >> selection;

switch (selection)  
{
  case 'P' || 'p':
  startgame();
  break;

  case 'Q' || 'q':
   // no poner un return sino cortar con un break
  //return;
    break;
}
return;
}
```

Igualmente yo cambiaría como usas los case, se me hace raro. Yo usaria algo asi:

```
case: 'P'
   EJECUTAS ALGO
case: 'p'
   OTRAS ACCIONES
```

lo mismo para tus otros casos

Comment: Okay, problema resuelto! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Tus 'case' están mal, por una sencilla razón: `'P' || 'p'` devuelve lo mismo que `'Q' || 'q'`, produciendo lo que se llama "etiqueta case duplicada":  `error: duplicate case value`.